# How can I deserialize a simple Json with square brackets in c#?

Tags: c#, json, api, deserialization

I don´t know what I´m doing wrong, but this is the Json I´m trying to read:

```
[{
    "object":
    {
        "Weigh": 4000
    }
}]
```

I really don´t know why I need the "object": part, but if I remove it, the code doesn´t work.

Here is my API Rest:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public string GetMixerTime([FromBody]JsonObject<WeighMix>[] json)
        {

            IList<WeighMix> listawm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WeighMix>>(json.ToString());

            return listawm.ToString();
        }
```

WeighMix class:

```
    public class WeighMix
    {
        public double Weigh { get; set; }

        public WeighMix()
        {
        }

        public WeighMix(double weigh)
        {
            Weigh = weigh;
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you share your WeighMix class?

Comment: It´s a simple class. I did it just to understand the concept because I need a bunch of them. I edited my question with the class.

Comment: In Visual Studio: `EDIT > PASTE SPECIAL > PASTE JSON AS CLASSES`

Comment: Where do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Square Brackets signifies Arrays in Json. Your Json is an array of type (say) A, which has a single property called object of type B (B matches the definition of WeighMix).

You need to change your class declaration as

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("object")]
    public WeighMix Object{get;set;}
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class WeighMix
    {
        public double Weigh { get; set; }

        public WeighMix()
        {
        }

        public WeighMix(double weigh)
        {
            Weigh = weigh;
        }
    }
```

You can now deserialize using

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

Sample Input

```
var json = @"[ { 'object': { 'weigh': 4000.0 }, 'json': '{\'Weigh\':4000.0}' } ]";
```

Sample Output

[image]

Comment: I still have this error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

Comment: In order to compile, i had to do it like this: var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<RootObject>>(json.ToString());

Comment: Are you using the same Json string as shown in OP ?

Comment: Yes, I had a diferent result when I had no square brackets. But when I added then, this error started to show up.

Comment: In order to try another approach, I made the API return the same Json that I received. And it´s working. But I can´t deserialize it to use the values.

Comment: This is what I get back:

Comment: [
    {
        "object": {
            "weigh": 4000.0
        },
        "json": "{\"Weigh\":4000.0}"
    }
]

Comment: @RenatoAzevedoZoppei I have updated the answer with Sample input you have provided. It was serialized successfully. Could you please verify once agin ?

Comment: First of all, I can´t thank you enough for don´t give up on me. Second, it worked. id I declare the var json like you did, it works just fine. But if I receive it from Angular, it just fails.

Comment: now I get it. The problem is here: IEnumerable<RootObject> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);

Comment: When I do it, I get an error: It says the json cannot be converted to string. So I added the json.ToString() to solve it. That´s why I was getting the error above.

Comment: But I don´t know why i´m getting the error tha says it cannot be converted to an string.

Comment: How can I convert a JasonObject to an string so I can deserialize it?

Comment: It´s like the oposite of jobject.parse

Comment: I DID IT!!!!!!!!!! Thank you so much!!! I´m working 7 hours to solve this, thank you very much!!! I just had to include: string json3 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json); before the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json3);